# WPF: Datagrid is updating header after adding or removing item at binding collection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, header

I have binded a ObservableCollection (loaded from an ORM) to a WPF-DataGrid and on programm start I'm changing the header titles, adding self-developed AutoFilters to the column headers and setting some columns to visibility collapsed. That works everything very well.

But if I'm adding an new or removing an excisting Item to/from the ObservableCollection then the DataGrid refreshes completely and I'm loosing the changed column titles, the AutoFilters and the columns I have collapsed on program start are also visible.

At the moment I don't know how I can solve this problem. I'm looking forward for your help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `AutoGenerateColumns` of the `DataGrid` to `False`.

For example:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

Comment: That's a good idea. Currently I'm using the AutoGenerateColumns-function when I'm loading the columns from the database but I don't really need it because the columns normaly not changes. Tomorrow I will try to code the columns fix in the code. When I'm ready I give a feedback if this is the solution...